# viper-mode で現在の state を確認するには？

Tags: elisp

viper-mode で、現在の state {Emacs,Vi,Insert} が何であるかを elisp 上で確認したいです。
これは、どうやったら実現できますか？

背景として、 state によって挙動が変わるような関数を定義したいからです。

Comment: `viper-current-state` という buffer local variable があるのでそれを利用するとか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viper-current-state` が求めているものでした。